# What is the proper verb to use instead of "being at the same time with" in this specific sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I want to tell a professor that I can not attend the meeting because it is at the same time as my class and ask them to change the meeting time. My question is, what is the correct word to use rather than "interfere" or "overlap"?

> The time you gave me for the weekly check-in meeting *interferes/overlaps* with my X class, which starts at 11:30. Can I come at a different time?

Also, I am using "The time you gave me" because it is a long meeting with different students, and each student is given a specific time to go. If you have a better suggestion for that, that would be great too.

Comment: I use “conflicts”.

Comment: I would use _clashes_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The time you gave me for the weekly check-in meeting interferes/overlaps with my X class, which starts at 11:30. Can I come at a different time?

On the 1st item, one other possible term is 'coincides'.

On the 2nd, 'The time you gave me' is fine.  You may consider 'have allocated to'.  I use present perfect as this is still current.

A possible update is hence

'The time you have allocated to me for the weekly check-in meeting coincides with my X class, which starts at 11:30. Can I come at a different time?'